# Binding from dynamically evaluated function on $scope to service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a function `make_value_summary` that generically makes a summary of `$scope` fields. Here I am using it to construct `location_summary`, bound to the view through `ng-bind`. `location_summary` is updated whenever the fields `street`, `suburb`, or `state` are updated.

```
$scope.location_summary = function() {
    var fields = [
        'street',
        'suburb',
        'state',
    ];
    return make_value_summary(fields, $scope, 'Location?');
};

function make_value_summary(fields, $scope, initial) {
    var summary = '';
    fields.forEach(function(field) {
        if ($scope[field] && $scope[field] !== '0') {
            if (summary) {
                summary = summary + ', ' + $scope[field];
            }
            else {
                summary = $scope[field];
            }
        }
    });
    if (summary) {
        return summary[0].toUpperCase() + summary.substring(1);
    }
    else {
        return initial;
    }
}
```

Question 1: How does `location_summary` get dynamically updated, from my initial look at the code it looks like `make_value_summary` should only be executed once when `location_summary` is first being assigned.

Question 2: I want to bind `location_summary` to a completely different part of the view through a service. How should I go about attaching `location_summary` to a service `Location`. I've tried using `$watch` but with no success.

```
$scope.$watch('location_summary', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    // Just gives unevaluated reference to location_summary function
    console.log(newValue);
    console.log(oldValue);
});
```

**EDIT**

Got a solution to 2. by 'evaluating' the function in the watch, i.e. pass in `'location_summary()'` to `$watch()`. Still would like an answer to my first question!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your codes, Please run this snippet.

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("appController",appController);

appController.$inject=["$scope"];
function appController($scope){
$scope.location_summary = function() {
    var fields = [
        'street',
        'suburb',
        'state',
    ];
    return make_value_summary(fields, $scope, 'Location?');
};

function make_value_summary(fields, $scope, initial) {
    var summary = '';
    fields.forEach(function(field) {
        if ($scope[field] && $scope[field] !== '0') {
            if (summary) {
                summary = summary + ', ' + $scope[field];
            }
            else {
                summary = $scope[field];
            }
        }
    });
    if (summary) {
        return summary[0].toUpperCase() + summary.substring(1);
    }
    else {
        return initial;
    }
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController">
  
  <input ng-model="street">
  <input ng-model="suburb">
  <input ng-model="state">
  
  {{location_summary()}}
  </body>
```